# Can we alias a question's title without creating a separate question?

Tags: feature-request, edits, search, title

For a long time, we have marked questions as duplicates as way of aliasing another question.

For example, I saw a question on a Stack Exchange site which was titled something like:

> I am *onfused with `__getattr__`. How do I **use** it?    (Question 1)

That question might be marked as a duplicate of a question titled something like this:

> How do I **override** `__getattr__` and why would I **override** `__getattr__`? (Question 2)

We mark questions as duplicates so that people who type "*use* `__getattr__`" into a search engine can find the questions about **overriding** a method without using the word **override**.

My suggested feature request is that editing a question title not be allowed by non-moderators anymore. Instead, we can ***alias*** a question.

At the bottom of every question we have the options "Share", "Edit", "Follow", and "Flag".

After clicking `Edit` we could be prompted to

1. Edit the body of the question.
2. Suggest alternative title.

When end users suggest an alternative title, then a message could be displayed worded something like, "suggested alternative title will be added to a queue until a moderator approves it".

I like that the original poorly worded questions make it easier for new programmers to find what they are looking for. There is almost no need to edit a poorly worded question title.

Sometimes, there is no duplicate question, and sometimes, more than one alias for a question would be nice.

Currently, question aliases are full-blown questions, for which there often a few answers posted and a lot of other features of a question or attributes of a question.

A question alias could simply be a string of 150 or fewer characters.

It is critical that question titles not be overly edited, otherwise students typing informal language into a search engine will not be able to find the question.

An alternative implementation might simply be to index all of the question titles in the version history.

A problem with that implementation is the original poorly worded question title and the new correct title should be both highly visible in the interface to end users without having to dive down into the version history.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331484/allow-unique-titles-of-automatically-deleted-duplicate-questions-to-remain-as-si

Comment: This seems to be lacking an explanation as to why it would be a good idea to do this. The only thing I see along those lines is "It is critical that question titles not be overly edited, otherwise students typing informal language into a search engine will not be able to find the question", but it's unclear how those concepts are actually related. Yes, the ability to find the question is substantially affected by the contents of the title and the title changes through editing, but what really matters is the actual *content* of the title, not the fact of editing.

Comment: So, preventing editing the title doesn't actually solve the problem of search-ability. In fact, it can hurt, as, perhaps, the existing title is poor and not very searchable. In such case, editing the title to something that's easier to find *helps significantly*. So, it's not the fact that an edit happened, that determines if it's good or bad, but the actual content, both before and after the edit. This feature request doesn't appear to be addressing the real issue for the only thing you've mentioned as an intended benefit.

Answer (score 13):

(quoting you. emphasis added.)

> My suggested feature-request is that **editing a question title not be allowed by non-moderators anymore**. Instead, we can alias a question. [...] When end-users suggest alternative title, then a message could be displayed worded something like, "suggested alternative title will be added to a queue until a moderator approves it".

Please no. Most people suck at writing titles- especially newer users, and especially people who don't have subject-matter expertise (not that subject-matter-experts are necessarily great at titles either- they can skew toward technical correctness in terminology that "newbies" may not google for, so balance is required, but they're generally better equipped for *disambiguation*, which is also very important in a title).

And have you noticed that in your example, there's a typo? ("*I am *onfused with __getattr__. How do I use it? (Question 1)*") UGH. Are you telling me it doesn't bother you? You think that typo makes the internet a better place? Honestly, if someone made me stare at it for one minute, I'd consider smashing my head into the nearest wall (okay- I'm exaggerating).

I'm for features that would allow for more easily adding alternate titles, which I think could be very useful particularly on meta sites (and especially here on MSE), but I don't see why we should prevent people who can actually write good titles from just making such edits.

Mods on large network sites are overworked already. This would crank how overworked they are into overdrive. This is not even "exception handling". We made editing a free community privilege for a reason.

> There is almost no need to edit a poorly worded question title.

Then explain the [Editor](/help/badges/3/editor), [Strunk & White](/help/badges/12/strunk-white), [Copy Editor](/help/badges/65/copy-editor), [Explainer](/help/badges/246/explainer), [Refiner](/help/badges/247/refiner), and [Illuminator](/help/badges/248/illuminator) badges. I encounter terrible, ambiguous, non-descriptive titles multiple times per day and it hurts me in my soul. It hurts me even more that you think they should stay that way and that somehow such titles are healthy in *any* way for the rest of the internet that benefits from Stack Exchange. Explain to me how bad titles contribute toward our goal of making the internet a better place. Bad titles make the internet a *worse* place. I hate clicking on a search result that sounds like it might be related to my question only to find out that it is not in fact related to my question.

Actually, the way your question post is arranged demonstrates why I dislike your feature-request. I like what you have proposed in your title ("*Can we alias a question's title without creating a separate question?*"), but I think your motivation for it is bunk, and I'm against how you actually suggest that the idea in your title be implemented. Now whenever someone searches up your title, they'll find this and might click away with a wrong impression that what your title itself suggests is a bad idea.